# Does IDA support segment:offset operands?

Tags: ida

Can I tell IDA that an operand is a segment:offset address? It doesn't seems to be any of the posibilities in the Offset (user-defined) dialog, however IDA uses them when decoding instructions with explicit segment addresses.

Comment: The answer is "yes". Add an example of what you're trying to handle if you want something more useful.

Comment: @Igor Skochinsky: Maybe you could elaborate about how you can "tell IDA that an operand is a segment:offset address".